# PHP print json_encode initial line break

Tags: php, printing, json, line-breaks

I am using phpunit to do some testing and I ran into a problem with

```
print json_encode($assoc_array);
```

I have an associative array

```
$assoc_array("username":"xxx");
```

In my_function() I print it out like this

```
print json_encode($assoc_array);
```

Then in my phpunit test I assert this

```
$output=my_function($assoc_array);
$expected='{"username":"xxx"}';
$this->assertEquals($expected,$output);
```

The assert returns false because $output is

```
$output='
{"username";"xxx"}';
```

and $expected is

```
$expected='{"username";"xxx"}';
```

For some reason I am getting a line break at the beginning when I use `print json_encode();`

I could just add a line break to all of my `$expected` values, but I really don't want to do that.  Why am I getting the line break?  Can anyone else get the line break too?

Comment: `echo json_encode($assoc_array);`

Comment: I don't get a line break. Are you sure there's no other line break earlier in your script? Maybe you have a blank line before `<?php`?

Comment: @KrishR What difference does that make? `echo` and `print` work the same way.

Comment: Try `print '|' . json_encode($assoc_array);`. Is the line before before or after `|`?

Comment: @Barmar There is a line break after the `'|'`

Comment: I `echo var_dump($assoc_array);` and I have a `\n` at the beginning.  It must be somewhere in my framework.  I'll go hunting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help @Barmar.  I found a line break after a `?>` in a controller.  I will remove all the `?>` from the class files.

Comment: I had the same problem! uahuahau, but it's ok now, program many classes has this kind of  trouble!